# How to send a request to server when the app is selected in home screen in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to send a request to server when the app is selected in home screen, before the login screen is displayed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can do it in the -()application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions delegate method of UIApplication –

Answer (score 0):

there were no springboard icon tap method or home screen icon selection method for any app that you can detect but when your app icon is being tapped on spring board then at the time of launching your app below method called first so you can write your code for sending request to server there :-

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```